# Does random forest machine learn support string character?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have some data like below:

```
username, password, valid
kramer, abcd1234, 1
dan,123123123,0
```

as you can see the character of the data can be string. So scikit-learn.RandomForestClassifier return error like

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'hEZ7P|N*Akem'
```

I am considering two solutions.

1. change string to float since they can be represented by ASCII
2. find another algothrim which support string feature.

Which one is better? Can you give some suggestion?

Comment: These algorithms require numerical input. What's your goal here?

Comment: I am trying to learn machine learn. So I design my use case. I created some data include user_name, password and valid. Valid or not is based on the password.    I try to let the algothrim train from my data. But I find that the algothrim can not handle string. So I asked here

Comment: I think machine learning is not the way to go. If you're using a password to validate something, then that's just direct logic - no statistical inference is required.

Comment: you are right.. this situation is too simple to use machine learn. But I just want to learn machine learn with this case

Comment: I understand that, but each password is going to be unique so there's no predictive ability from this column as it stands. You could use this as a lesson in feature engineering though. Create columns such as 'pass_length" which is the length of the password, or "has_capital" which is 1 if the password contains capital letters, or "numeric_count" which counts the number of numbers in the password, etc. Then you'll have some columns on which you can train.

Comment: wow!!!!   thanks  great. I think that will work.      very appreciate!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to encode the categorical features with something like one-hot encoding since you need numerical representation. Check this answer out for more

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/strings-as-features-in-decision-tree-random-forest

Comment: Thanks for the information. I learned one-hot encoding. But it seems not fit for my situation. Since the password is too long, it will use too much space.

Comment: Can you elaborate what the task is? What you are trying to do? The way in which string are encoded might not be an obvious one and it might differ depending on what you are trying to do here. You are using the username and passwords as input for classification I presume. But what are you classifying, whats the intuition here?  Edit : I think Jared Stufft's comment answers the question. This was not really a scenario in which machine learning can be applied. The inputs/features that you use have to relate to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I want to emulate a use case which need machine learn to solve.  So I create some data. the username and password is input and valid is the class.  I understand that this may not be a very good example now.. Trying to find a more appropriate one

Comment: Ok. Make sure you understand what question you are trying to answer. Once you have that, try and see what kind of 'data' would it depend on. What can be the feature. For example, if you had a output classifying whether or not a password was secure, the length could be a reasonable feature (Like Jared mentioned above in the comments). Make sure you have got the question clear and then make sure you have the appropriate inputs to model the problem you are trying to solve.